# How to alter the default font displayed INSIDE CKeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I would like to be able to alter the font in the [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) (version 7.x-1.15) module so that it does not show Times New Roman, but rather the font that the rest of the site uses, Helvetica. I'm using Drupal 7.30.

When CKeditor loads when content is edited it always shows Times New Roman!

[image: CKeditor with Times New Roman (default) font]

I have altered 'Custom Javascript configuration' in:

admin/config/content/ckeditor > Advanced options to read:

```
config.extraCss += "body{font-family:Helvetica, serif;}";
```

Cleared all Drupal caches AND browser caches - nothing.

I've also altered:

ckeditor.config.js - line 36:

```
config.extraCss = 'font-family:Helvetica;color:#726F6F;';
```

Again, cleared all caches - nothing!

Please could someone explain what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is set in ckeditor/ckeditor/contents.css, although it is generally inadvisable to alter a module, it can be done safely so long as you document the changes (in the event that updates are required and would overwrite your work).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Geoff for providing the path to the content.css file.

[image]